# Facebook SDK Android - Error code 1- kError 1357038

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-3.1

I am getting error as below image while sharing on facebook from my android app.

[image]

I tried below options too 
[this](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=625072634191702) 
I had tried to close browser and logout from my facebook app in android but still not solved.
Please guide me
Thanks,